# How to keep track of original row indices in Numpy array when comparing to only a slice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with a 2D numpy array A, performing a comparison of a one dimensional array, X, against each row in A. As approximate matches are found, I'm keeping track of their indices in A in a dtype=bool array S. I'd like to use S to shrink the field of match candidates in A to improve efficiency. Here's the basic idea in code:

```
def compare(nxt):
    S[nxt] = 0  #sets boolean 
    T = A[nxt, i:] == A[S, :-i] #T has different dimesions than A
```

compare() is iterated over and S is progressively populated with False values.

The problem is that the boolean array T is of the same dimensions as the pared down version of A not the original version. I'm hoping to use T to get the indices (in the unsliced A) of the approximate matches for later use.

```
np.argwhere(T)
```

This returns a list of indices of the matches, but again in the slice of A.

It seems like there has to be a better way to, at the same time, crop A for more efficient searching and still be able to get the correct index of the matching row.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Really need a [mcve] here.  Runnable code, test input, expected output.  It seems like an answerable question but there's just not enough information here to be sure what you want.

Comment: How are you finding matches? This seems like a good use of correlation;
 you can use [`np.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html).